# I can't execute anything on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

```
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# test -f
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# test -f lib/libncurses.so.5
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# test -f lib/libncurses.so.5 && echo 's'
s
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# test -f lib/libncurses.so.5 && echo 's' || echo 'f'
s
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# test -f lib/libdl.so.2 && echo 's' || echo 'f'
s
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# test -f lib/libc.so.6 && echo 's' || echo 'f'
s
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# test -f lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && echo 's' || echo 'f'
f
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# cd lib
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib# find . -name 'ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
./ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib# cd ..
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# cd lib64
bash: cd: lib64: no such file or directory
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# mkdir lib64
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# cd lib64
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64# cp -a /lib64 .
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64# ls
lib64
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64# cd lib64
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64/lib64# ls
cpp                                   libgcc_s.so.1                libply-splash-core.so.2
dbus-1.0                              libgcrypt.so.11              libply-splash-core.so.2.0.0
firmware                              libgcrypt.so.11.5.2          libply-splash-graphics.so.2
hdparm                                libglib-2.0.so.0             libply-splash-graphics.so.2.0.0
init                                  libglib-2.0.so.0.2400.1      libply.so.2
klibc-usBAintlt99f0TITo98H_trqH2c.so  libgpg-error.so.0            libply.so.2.0.0
ld-2.11.1.so                          libgpg-error.so.0.4.0        libpng12.so.0
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2                  libhistory.so.5              libpng12.so.0.42.0
ld-linux.so.2                         libhistory.so.5.2            libpopt.so.0
libBrokenLocale-2.11.1.so             libhistory.so.6              libpopt.so.0.0.0
libBrokenLocale.so.1                  libhistory.so.6.1            libproc-3.2.8.so
libSegFault.so                        libiptc.so.0                 libpthread-2.11.1.so
libacl.so.1                           libiptc.so.0.0.0             libpthread.so.0
libacl.so.1.1.0                       libiw.so.30                  libreadline.so.5
libanl-2.11.1.so                      libkeyutils-1.2.so           libreadline.so.5.2
libanl.so.1                           libkeyutils.so.1             libreadline.so.6
libatasmart.so.4                      libm-2.11.1.so               libreadline.so.6.1
libatasmart.so.4.0.3                  libm.so.6                    libresolv-2.11.1.so
libatm.so.1                           libmemusage.so               libresolv.so.2
libatm.so.1.0.0                       libncurses.so.5              librt-2.11.1.so
libattr.so.1                          libncurses.so.5.7            librt.so.1
libattr.so.1.1.0                      libncursesw.so.5             libselinux.so.1
libblkid.so.1                         libncursesw.so.5.7           libsepol.so.1
libblkid.so.1.1.0                     libnih-dbus.so.1             libslang.so.2
libbsd.so.0                           libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0         libslang.so.2.2.2
libbsd.so.0.2.0                       libnih.so.1                  libss.so.2
libbz2.so.1                           libnih.so.1.0.0              libss.so.2.0
libbz2.so.1.0                         libnsl-2.11.1.so             libssl.so.0.9.8
libbz2.so.1.0.4                       libnsl.so.1                  libsysfs.so.2
libc-2.11.1.so                        libnss_compat-2.11.1.so      libsysfs.so.2.0.1
libc.so.6                             libnss_compat.so.2           libthread_db-1.0.so
libcap.so.2                           libnss_dns-2.11.1.so         libthread_db.so.1
libcap.so.2.17                        libnss_dns.so.2              libtic.so.5
libcidn-2.11.1.so                     libnss_files-2.11.1.so       libtic.so.5.7
libcidn.so.1                          libnss_files.so.2            libticw.so.5
libcom_err.so.2                       libnss_hesiod-2.11.1.so      libticw.so.5.7
libcom_err.so.2.1                     libnss_hesiod.so.2           libudev.so.0
libcrypt-2.11.1.so                    libnss_mdns.so.2             libudev.so.0.6.1
libcrypt.so.1                         libnss_mdns4.so.2            libulockmgr.so.1
libcrypto.so.0.9.8                    libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2    libulockmgr.so.1.0.1
libdbus-1.so                          libnss_mdns6.so.2            libusb-0.1.so.4
libdbus-1.so.3                        libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2    libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
libdbus-1.so.3.4.0                    libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2     libusb-1.0.so.0
libdevmapper.so.1.02.1                libnss_nis-2.11.1.so         libusb-1.0.so.0.0.0
libdl-2.11.1.so                       libnss_nis.so.2              libutil-2.11.1.so
libdl.so.2                            libnss_nisplus-2.11.1.so     libutil.so.1
libdrm.so.2                           libnss_nisplus.so.2          libuuid.so.1
libdrm.so.2.4.0                       libntfs-3g.so.75             libuuid.so.1.3.0
libdrm_intel.so.1                     libntfs-3g.so.75.0.0         libwrap.so.0
libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0                 libpam.so.0                  libwrap.so.0.7.6
libdrm_nouveau.so.1                   libpam.so.0.82.2             libxtables.so.2
libdrm_nouveau.so.1.0.0               libpam_misc.so.0             libxtables.so.2.0.0
libdrm_radeon.so.1                    libpam_misc.so.0.82.0        libz.so.1
libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.0                libpamc.so.0                 libz.so.1.2.3.3
libe2p.so.2                           libpamc.so.0.82.1            lsb
libe2p.so.2.3                         libparted.so.0               modules
libexpat.so.1                         libparted.so.0.0.1           plymouth
libexpat.so.1.5.2                     libpcprofile.so              security
libexpatw.so.1                        libpcre.so.3                 terminfo
libexpatw.so.1.5.2                    libpcre.so.3.12.1            udev
libext2fs.so.2                        libpcsclite.so.1             ufw
libext2fs.so.2.4                      libpcsclite.so.1.0.0         xtables
libfuse.so.2                          libply-boot-client.so.2
libfuse.so.2.8.1                      libply-boot-client.so.2.0.0
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64/lib64# mv * ../
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64/lib64# cd ..
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64# ls
bash: /bin/ls: no such file or directory
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64# ls
bash: /bin/ls: no such file or directory
root@dd:/tmp/chroot/lib64# cd ..
root@dd:/tmp/chroot# ls
bash: /bin/ls: no such file or directory
root@dd:/tmp/chroot#
```

First of all, sorry for bad english...
As seen above, even though the server did not perform a delete command has failed. Why is this happening? How do I import my local files? (SFTP, FTP is not working now T_T)

Comment: *edit* scratch that, I see it happens outside the chroot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/chroot/lib
/tmp/chroot/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/ls
```

Comment: thanks but.. when I type code, It prints "bash: export: `/bin/ls': not valid name"...

Comment: but without export... it works!!!

Comment: these are two distinct commands. sorry for the edit storm.

Comment: it will work as a single line without export, but then you will have to prepend every time. IF both systems (in and out of chroot) are amd64, you can now probably make a copy command work to replace the linker in the outer system.

Comment: How can I recover this system? I want to use other commands, but it failed "/bin/clear: error while loading shared libraries: /bin/clear: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: The first thing you need is to fix the /lib directory on the outer system. as i said, if / and /tmp/chroot point to system of the same architecture, you can copy most things you need from /tmp/chroot/lib.

Comment: Still: now the next thing is to find out WHY parts of /lib went missing in action. This looks like either filesystem corruption (fsck -vf as soon as you can!) or some (maybe successful, maybe not) attempt at manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

First place I would start is by checking if that /bin directory is intact.  You can do this by executing the following:

```
cd /bin
echo *
```

Could also have been the doing of someone who has comprimised your system and is looking to cover their tracks as well.  First thing you likely want to do is load up a live CD and check the md5's. [/bin/ls not found even though it exists](https://serverfault.com/questions/10884/bin-ls-not-found-even-though-it-exists).

Comment: Thanks. bin folder exists and files in bin folder exists too.

Comment: if you enter echo $PATH is /bin listed?

Comment: # echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: Yes, and I think everything works fine now. Many thanks again T_T