# Auth.log understand it

Tags: ubuntu, security

I have an ubuntu server and I want to understand if someone enter into it (hacker).
I have seen into auth.log many lines like this:

```
May 30 10:36:00 xxx-System-Product_Name CRON[2758]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
May 30 10:36:00 xxx-System-Product_Name CRON[2758]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user admin
May 30 10:37:00 xxx-System-Product_Name CRON[2759]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
May 30 10:37:00 xxx-System-Product_Name CRON[2759]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user admin
```

My user is 'alessandro' and not admin someone is entered with user 'admin' ?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try doing a `sudo crontab -u admin -e`..

Comment: print me: * * * * * /var/tmp/.kitten/.update >/dev/null 2>&1 @NickW

Comment: That is interesting, what's in that file?

Comment: empty /dev/null and /var/tmp/.kitten I can't find this @NickW

Comment: So if you do a `sudo ls -la /var/tmp/` you do not see anything?

Comment: `/dev/null` is empty always, it's like a hole to throw things down, un buco nero dove non torna indietro niente..

Comment: i have . .. .ssh with commad ls -la /var/tmp/

Comment: An italian description of /dev/null is like pure poetry. +1.

Comment: So you're sure that there is nothing in /var/tmp/ ..

Comment: there is .ssh but not .kitten or something else @NickW

Comment: Maybe there was something, it's not a comforting thought honestly.. nobody else should have access to this server, correct? Even the .ssh in /var/tmp is odd.

Comment: nobody have access I'm only that have all password, but I don't know if someone can enter. in .ssh there are other folder and files

Comment: who is the owner of the files in /var/tmp/.ssh ?

Comment: is admin the owner @NickW

Comment: If you can't be sure who might have created that user and those files, you might want to look through this.. and make your own decision: http://serverfault.com/questions/6190/reinstall-after-a-root-compromise

Answer (score 4):

Your comments reveal files and directory structures which are commonly seen with rootkits. So it's a very high probability that your server has been compromised and taken over. You should begin remediation as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok understand, I can't reinstall all can I do something like change permission to this file, deny ssh access?

Comment: As you don't know how they got in, it's going to be difficult to understand what they changed, and above all, prevent them from doing it again. I'd advise you to set up plans to create a new server as soon as possible. By all means, block ssh access, but it's not a solution, just a small plaster on a big wound.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri See the duplicate question yours now points to - the general advice is to reinstall the whole machine (because you don't know how they got in). I'm not sure what `/var/tmp/.kitten/.update` contains (you can look at the file with `cat /var/tmp/.kitten/.update` to see if you recognize its contents), but the directory structure is definitely suspect -- normally crontabs don't point at things in temporary directories...